# error 800A1C2 on my code

Tags: vbscript

I have a code that is supposed to download an image from the Internet and set it as wallpaper, but it keeps saying that there is a wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: `SaveToFile`.

```
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/compositions/1009468864/views/1,width=300,height=300,version=145225706    1/anonymous-seal-t-shirts-men-s-tall-t-shirt.jpg", False
xHttp.Send

With bStrm
  .Type = 1 '//binary
  .Open
  .Write xHttp.responseBody
  .Savetofile "C:\Users\",strUser,"\downloads", 2 '//overwrite
End With

Dim wshShell 
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("strUser")

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sWinDir = oFSO.GetSpecialFolder(0) 
sWallPaper = "C:\Users\eskonr\Pictures\Nice-Windows-7.jpg"

' update in registry 
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", sWallPaper

' let the system know about the change 
oShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True

MsgBox "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .SaveToFile "C:\Users\",strUser,"\downloads", 2 '//overwrite
> ```

You're trying to call `.SaveToFile` with 4 parameters: `"C:\Users\"`, `strUser`, `"\downloads"`, and `2`, when you apparently want to build a path from the first three elements. Use the concatenation operator for that:

```
.SaveToFile "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\downloads", 2 '//overwrite
```